# Using jquery to capture all hash clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any way to use jquery to capture all/any hash tag (#xxxxx) clicks? Can't put them under one class.

Comment: What do you mean by hash tag clicks?

Comment: he probably means the on-content link like `<a href='#chapter1'>Scroll to chapter 1</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following code will do:

```
$('a[href*=#]').click( function() { /* do something */ } );
```

or you can use a more efficient method as JamWaffles pointed out:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href*=#]', function() { /* do something */ });
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to do something when your page is loaded with a #hash in url, then you will need to take a look at the [jQuery hashchange plugin by Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)

here is the piece of code you basically need to add to your page ( above code wont be needed in this particular case )

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $(window).hashchange( function(){
        // Alerts every time the hash changes!
        alert( location.hash );  
    })
    if( location.href.indexOf('#') > -1 )
    {
        $(window).trigger('hashchange'); // this will trigger the first time the page is loaded if there is a hash in your url
    }
});
```

Comment: You might want to bind a delegated event to `<body>` to make this more efficient. Currently, you're binding an event to every matched element.

Comment: It's a statement of affirmation.

Comment: i get it, if you were citing your answer for saying that, then its no problem my friend, sometimes we learn and sometimes we teach :).
@JamWaffles can you clarify a bit more.

Comment: As in, `$('body').on('click', 'a[href*=#]', function() { ... });` (providing you're using jQuery 1.7+). Here, you're only binding one event handler instead of potentially hundreds.

Comment: One last thing - this only captures if it is a click. Any way to capture it if the page is loaded with a hashtag?

Comment: you mean to say that you want to track if the follows an external link or a direct url to your page and that url includes a hashtag and you want to do some action on that particular event?

Comment: Yeah. The code there does 99% - but what if the page is loaded with the #xxxx hashtag in place? (and thus no click to catch it).

I've hacked it with a form of 
> if ( window.location.hash ) { xxxxxxxxxxxxxx } but it seems a bit ugly.

Comment: i have updated my answer try this, here is a working jsfiddle demo so you can check, (which is not developed by me though) http://jsfiddle.net/HNMfU/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("#") > -1) {
        $(this).bind("click", hashListener);
        // where hashListener is the name of your
        // tracking function.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
  if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#') == 0 || $(this).attr('href').indexOf(window.location.href+"#") == 0){
    // do your stuff here.
  }
});
```

This code *should* take care of both relative and absolute hash tags.